# Heads-up Notification not showing in android 12

Tags: android, heads-up-notifications

I have added two action in this head-up notification Answer and Reject . which is worked in all device under android-12.

But in android 12 this type of notification not showing .
what the exact problem i don't know I read documentation but not found any solution. [image: call_screenshot]

I checked all notification setting of app inside my device.
Is in android 12 any changes regarding this type of notification .
please your answer will help us thanks.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this in my project using below code
First of all, add permission in AnroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
```

Now set **full screen intent** in your notification builder with your activity as below:

```
var answerCallIntent = Intent(this@FirebaseInstanceService, AnswerDeclineCallActivity::class.java)
var answerCallPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this@FirebaseInstanceService,
   0, answerCallIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
   setFullScreenIntent(answerCallPendingIntent, true)
```

Note : Some devices like Xiaomi, you have to redirect user to settings to enable "show on lock screen" permission to show activity in lockscreen.

**Make sure you have set priority to max in notification builder:**

```
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX) //Important for heads-up notification
```